# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 with Apache POI 3.9 and Java JDK 1.7

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm try to create an easy program which generates a xls file, so I'm using `APACHE POI 3.9`. When I run that project, I have an excepcion:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: GenerarExcel/PruebaGenerarExcel : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I know that the reason why it doesn't work is because I must update my JDK (in fact, I did the same with JDK 1.8 and it works correctly), but one of the requirements of the program is that it must work with JDK 1.7.

I tried with JExcel API and I had the same problem.

Do you know which JAVA API I can use to generate that excel .xls document?

Comment: You have compiled your code with Java 8, but are running it with Java 7.

Comment: The Java compiler `javac` supports some options for compatibility (`-source` and `-target`). Check Oracles website for `javac` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much Mark!